Excisive couples in simplicial homology
I am reading "Elements of algebraic topology" by Munkres and here is an exercise(34.1):
Prove, that if K1 and K2 are subcomplexes of K, then {|K1|, |K2|} is an excisive couple in singular theory. One of two definitions of excisive couple, is, that the inclusion map $(|K1|,|K1|\cap|K2|)\to (|K|,|K2|)$ induces an isomorphism in homology.
Since all the objects in the statement are simplicial complexes, we can use the simplicial theory as well.
The problem is, that I think, I have founded a counterexample to the exercise:
Let K1 be just a 1-simplex, and K2 be one of its vertices. Let K be two disjoint 1-simpleces (one of them is K1).
Then, the 0-homology group of $(|K1|,|K1|\cap|K2|)$ is trivial, while 0-homology group of $(|K|,|K2|)$ is infinite cyclic, so they are not isomorphic.
I want to ask where is my mistake and what is the right solution for the exercise.
As far as I understood, an excisive couple must not satisfy the property, that $|K1|\cup|K2|=|K|$

You probably mean "Elements of algebraic topology" instead of "Elements of topological algebra".

@M.G., yes, I meant "Elements of topological algebra"; Thank you for your correction

Excisive (not excesive) couples are defined in two places. On page 149, $(X_1,X_2)$ is called an excisive couple if the pairs  inclusion $(X_1,X_1\cap X_2)\to(X_1\cup X_2,X_2)$ induces a homology isomorphism. On page 186, $(X_1,X_2)$ is called an excisive couple if the inclusion $\mathscr S(X_1)+\mathscr S(X_2)\to\mathscr S(X_1\cup X_2)$ is a homology isomorphism. With regard to your example, this means that additionally $K$ must be union of $K_1$ and $K_2$.

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე Why not an official answer?

No worries, but excisive is the math-jargon, not to be confused with excessive [I originally misread you as saying this one] which means something completely different.

According to the definition of excisive couples on page 149 (see also page 186), in addition it is required that $|K_1|\cup|K_2|=|K|$. Indeed otherwise there would be no chance to relate the pairs $(|K_1|,|K_1|\cap|K_2|)$ and $(|K|,|K_2|)$ as you would be able to add to the second anything at all independently of the first.
